# AngularJS, applying $location.search('foo', 'bar') and manually removing url params does not refresh

Tags: angularjs, url, location

Right now, I have a path, let's say `/path`, in an AngularJS application (which is not a single-paged app).

I want to set certain parameters in the URL to keep filters and sorting intact when I refresh.  To do so, I used `$location.search('foo', 'bar')`, which appropriately changes the URL to `/path?foo=bar`.  When I refresh, I can access foo with $location.search().foo.  So far so good.

However, a problem arises when I manually edit the url.  In particular, I've found when I erase `?foo=bar` from my url and press enter once, nothing happens.  If I click the url bar again and press enter, it reloads the page as expected.

Is there a reason it doesn't work the first time?  Is there a non-intrusive way to get around this issue?  Usage of non-angular methods is okay, but we're trying to avoid putting Jquery into the application.